# Radio Station Happiness

Tags: fallout-shelter

I understand that the Radio Station generates a level of Happiness for all the Vault Dwellers and high Charisma is helpful as well, but my question is when the Radio Station is successful in recruiting a new Dweller and the room is waiting for your to tap it, does the Radio Station continue to provide Happiness?

I don't always want to bring a new Survivor into the Vault but I do want the Happiness Boost from a fully upgraded and fully staffed (Charisma 10) Radio Station.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how the happiness from radio bonus works, but remember that you can have up to 10 potential dwellers waiting in line outside the vault, so you can tap on the radio room without bringing the new dweller into the vault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I'm under the impression that the happiness boost from the radio station is a passive benefit, rather than gained upon activation. I've been ignoring the fully-staffed (max charisma) triple room radio in my vault because I don't want new dwellers right now, and my population is sitting at around 91% happiness. I haven't started to manage my dwellers to improve happiness (e.g. by having low-happiness dwellers start families) beyond putting both males and females working together in each room.

Comment: one of the things I actually saw on mine was the happiness of the people in training went up from 75% to 76% though I only have a 2 block fully upgraded broadcast center.  Not much but considering 50% of my dwellers are in training it adds up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

if you've seen ,what has happened with a new update,it was written there that radio is "passively" increasing happiness of all dwellers in the vault,but if you tap on the radio once,there is a chance to decide whether you want it to broadcast outside(+inside) or just inside therefore attract new dwellers(and increase happiness) or just increase happiness.
According to my experience, if you have 3 merged rooms and all 6 people there with high charisma it is "happier" than 3 merged and ,say, 4 people there with same stats